# Blank Imagefield with foreign key in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models: `users` and `comments`

```
class GRUser(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'gruser'

    def avatar_big_path(self, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        return 'images/user_avatars/big/{0}.{1}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), ext)

    def avatar_small_path(self, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        return 'images/user_avatars/small/{0}.{1}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), ext)

    facebook_link = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)
    avatar_big = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_big_path, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar_small = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_small_path, null=True, blank=True)


class VideoComment(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'video_comment'
    video_comment_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent_comment_fk = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='child_comments',
                                          db_column='parent_comment_fk')
    video_fk = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='video_comments', db_column='video_fk')
    user_fk = models.ForeignKey(GRUser, related_name='video_comments', db_column='user_fk')
    video_comment_dttm = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

and their ModelSerializers:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.GRUser
        fields = ('id',
                  'username',
                  'email',
                  'avatar_big',
                  'avatar_small',
                  )    

class VideoCommentListRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user_fk.username')
    avatar_small = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user_fk.avatar_small')

    class Meta:
        model = models.VideoComment
        fields = ('video_comment_pk',
                  'parent_comment_fk',
                  'video_fk',
                  'user_fk',
                  'username',
                  'avatar_small',
                  'video_comment_dttm',
                  'text',
                  )
```

There are some users with blank `avatar_small` attribute. In the user list they are displayed as

```
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "admin@gmail.com",
        "avatar_big": null,
        "avatar_small": null
    },
```

However, in comments list the same users raise an error:

```
The `avatar_small` attribute has no file associated with it.
```

I solved this problem using `SerializerMethodField`

```
avatar_small = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_avatar_small(self, obj):
    if obj.user_fk.avatar_small:
        return obj.user_fk.avatar_small.url
    else:
        return None
```

Is there a more convenient way to deal with it? 
Why `ModelSerializer` doesn't display `null` by default?

Comment: did you try `avatar_small = serializers.RelatedField(source='user_fk.avatar_small', read_only=True)` rather than `avatar_small = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user_fk.avatar_small')
` ?

Comment: @AhmedHosny yes, it returns the following error:
"RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field avatar_small. If you do not need to support write operations you probably want to subclass `ReadOnlyField` instead."

Comment: Try this `user = UserListSerializer(source='user')` then choose fields the same way now.

Comment: @AhmedHosny nested serializer works well but I didn't want to have nested structure

Comment: So, There is another way to do it if you override `__unicode__` function inside model to print the value of avatar_small, then use just `avatar_small = serializers.RelatedField(source='user_fk', read_only=True)` but I don't think that it will be a good idea.

Comment: also please try avatar_small = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user_fk.avatar_small.url')?

Comment: I've already tried it( 
I'am wondering why ModelSerializer behaves differently when a foreign key gets involved.